# Knockout observable behaviour

Tags: knockout-2.0

I have two fields:

```
Vm.field1 = ko.observable("something");
Vm.field2 = ko.observable(Vm.field1());

Vm.field1("x")
```

When I set new value to field1 , subscribe method of field2 is invoke with value "x" . Has field2 reference to field1 on change value? Why it happends?

Comment: that shouldn't happen, there has to be something wrong with your code, could you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an observable into another one, it will automatically subscribe value change event  that's the default behavior of knockout observable.

Comment: that's the case only in computed observables, normal observables does not subscribe to other ones implicitly.

Comment: Are you sure Anas? Have you tried to create an example before making the comment?